# Linux C++ Watchdog for server

Tags: c++, linux, raspberry-pi

I'm developing a system on a Raspberry Pi that uses a web interface to interact with it, and has a custom C++ server. The idea is, that you just plug in the Pi and don't need to start the server manually. While this isn't a problem, the server sometimes segfaults. I can't avoid it, so I want to have a watchdog program continually running to check whether the server has segfaulted, and if it has, restart it. I've tried to look up how to do this in C with fork, but I couldn't find any answer that makes sense.

It doesn't have to be a C program, just something that works. It needs to work on Raspbian (Debian for RPi)

Comment: Add your program to `/etc/inittab` as a `respawn` process.  I don't know anything about Raspbian so I'll just leave this as a comment.

Comment: OK, would I then have to include run level 1 (as the user never logs in?) If that is the case, I guess it would look like `1:12345:respawn:/path/to/server`?

Comment: Yes, that would probably work.  You just need it in the runlevel that your system boots into.

Answer (score 2):

It's best if you fix the segfault. But, if it's not possible at the moment, write a script to check for the running process by calling `ps aux |grep nameofyourprogram` if returns nothing run the program again. Or write a program which will frequently try to connect to the server's port if fails, run the server again. Hope this trick will help!

Comment: Of course I'd like to fix it, but it occurs so rarely that I can't get a stack trace on it. I'll try the script